# RSpec with FactoryGirl explicit subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using RSpec with FactoryGirl within a Ruby on Rails environment for testing.

I want to specify my factories as follows:

```
  factory :user do
    role # stub

    factory :resident do
      association :role, factory: :resident_role
    end

    factory :admin do
      association :role, factory: :admin_role
    end
  end
```

And I'd like to do something like this in my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context "all users" do
    # describe a user
    #   subject { build(:user) }
    #   it { is_expected.to be_something_or_do_something }
  end

  context "residents" do
    # describe a resident
    #   subject { build(:resident) }
    #   it { is_expected.to be_something_or_do_something }
  end

  context "admins" do
    # describe a admin
    #   subject { build(:admin) }
    #   it { is_expected.to be_something_or_do_something }
  end

end
```

Can this be done by explicitly setting the `subject`? When I do, I keep getting duplicate roles errors.

If anyone has any advice or suggestion, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this causes the user_spec.rb to use the :user factory.

No, it does not. Assuming you configured FactoryGirl correctly, RSpec can use whatever factory you'd like "on demand" in any test file. Configuration-wise, in `rails_helper.rb` throw this in:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   # ...
   config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
   # ...
end
```

Then, in your spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context "all users" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) } 

    it 'is a user' do 
      # Here `user` is going to be a user factory
      expect(user.unit).not_to be_present
    end

  end

  context "residents" do
    let(:user) { create(:resident) } 

    it 'is a resident' do 
      # Here `user` is going to be a resident factory
      expect(user.unit).to be_present
    end
  end

  context "admins" do
    let(:user) { create(:admin) } 

    it 'is an admin' do 
      # Here `user` is going to be an admin factory
      expect(user.role).to be('admin_role')
    end
  end

end
```

In short, you can use `create(<factory_name>)` on any factory definition that exists in any one of these paths:

```
test/factories.rb
spec/factories.rb
test/factories/*.rb
spec/factories/*.rb
```

Note that if you haven't placed the `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` inside your `RSpec.configure`, you can still create any factory, by doing `FactoryGirl.create(<factory_name>)` instead of `create(<factory_name>)`.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure? I just ran a `raise subject.inspect` on a similar spec of mine, with a factory named as the model and the spec, and I do not observe such behavior. My implicit `subject` is a `<ModelClass>.new` (default behavior of RSpec), not a `FactoryGirl.build(:model_class)`. What do you observe on your end?

Comment: You're right it is a blank model instance! Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to stop them from auto loading, and I'm not actually sure what your use case is for not allowing them to load?

`RSpec automagically fetches the factory for a spec`
Rspec loads all the factories into memory when your spec helper loads I believe. Because your using factory inheritence your just loading each of these into memory before your tests run, nothing is being called, no objects are being created or built. They are just ready to use in your tests.

Are you getting a specific error or is there some case I'm not seeing that you need?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problems here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

What I needed to use in my user factories was `association :role, factory: :role, strategy: :build`